# Solving $\ln(x)/\ln(y) > x/y$

Tags: inequality

Given $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$, find, with proof, all solutions to

$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)} > \frac{x}{y}.$$

I had suspected it to be true when $y>x$ and $x, y \neq 1$ (graph on WolframAlpha seems to agree), but I don't know how to prove it.

EDIT: I believe I found a solution, but I'm uncertain as to the bounds, and whether there's a simpler way of expressing my answer.

Suppose $y = ax$, where $a \neq 1$. Since $x$ and $y$ are both positive, $a > 0$. Then, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y\ln(x) &> x\ln(y)\\
\ln(x^y) &> \ln(y^x)\\
x^{(ax)} &> (ax)^x\\
x^a &> ax\\
x^{a-1} &> a\\
x &> a^{\frac{1}{a-1}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
This, along with $y = ax$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\backslash\{1\}$, gives us a solution. However, is there a way to simplify this rather unwieldy expression?

Thanks.

Comment: What are $a,b$ ?

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed it and added a possible solution.

Comment: @user503127  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint: for $\ln{y} > 0$ that is $y>1$ consider the equivalent $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x} > \frac{\ln(y)}{y}$$

for $\ln{y} < 0$ that is $0<y<1$  consider the equivalent $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x} < \frac{\ln(y)}{y}$$

and study the function $$f(z)=\frac{\ln(z)}{z}$$

as $f(z)$ is strictly increasing for $0<z \leq e$ and strictly decreasing for $z \geq e$ the solution are:

when $y>1$ $$e \leq x <y$$ $$1 < y <x \leq e$$

when $0<y<1$ $$0 < x<y <1$$

Comment: $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x} > \frac{\ln(y)}{y}$$ Is NOT equivalent to $$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln (y)} > \frac{x}{y}$$

Comment: you are right, it' only valid for for x,y >1

Comment: Anyway, the study of $f$ will suffice.

Comment: I've corrected the statement :), is it ok now?

Comment: @Yves Daoust and now?

Comment: Sorry, it's correct now.

Comment: I've just posted a complete solution